# Relaxed Memory Ordering in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to understand `Relaxed Memory Ordering` of C++11. My understanding is as :

```
This ordering guarantees that the ordering of operations on a 
particular atomic variable doesn't change but ordering
of operations of different atomic variables can change. The ordering here is
within the same thread. For example, 

Thread 1
operation A on atomic X
operation B on atomic Y
operation C on atomic Y
operation D on atomic X

Relaxed ordering guarantees that operation A will always happen-before
operation D and operation B will always happen-before operation C. 
Having said that, the ordering of operations between X & Y can still change.
That is, suppose the original code was like above. One possible execution
order could be:
operation A on atomic X
operation D on atomic X
operation B on atomic Y
operation C on atomic Y
```

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

I wrote a sample code below to test `Relaxed Memory Ordering` and expected `assert` to fail sometime. But it never fails. I built this program on `Visual Studio 2017` and running on `Windows 10` with `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6600U CPU@ 2.60GHz 2.80GHz`

```
class RelaxedMemoryOrdering{
#define ARRAY_SIZE 4096
public:
  static int var_array[ARRAY_SIZE];
  RelaxedMemoryOrdering() {
    for (int index = 0; index < ARRAY_SIZE; ++index) {
      var_array[index] = 0;
    }
    sync1 = 0;
    sync2 = 0;
    sync3 = 0;
    sync4 = 0;
    sync5 = 0;
    }

  void thread1() {
    sync1.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    sync2.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    sync3.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);

    for (int index = 0; index < ARRAY_SIZE; ++index) {
        var_array[index] = index + 1;
    }

    sync4.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    sync5.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
  }

  void thread2() {
    while (!sync5.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
      ;
    }

    assert(sync4.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1);

    for (int index = 0; index < ARRAY_SIZE; ++index) {
        assert(RelaxedMemoryOrdering::var_array[index] == (index + 1));
    }

    assert(sync3.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1);
    assert(sync2.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1);
    assert(sync1.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1);
  }

  void Test() {
    std::thread t1(&RelaxedMemoryOrdering::thread1, this);
    std::thread t2(&RelaxedMemoryOrdering::thread2, this);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
  }

private:
  std::atomic_int sync1{0};
  std::atomic_int sync2{0};
  std::atomic_int sync3{0};
  std::atomic_int sync4{0};
  std::atomic_int sync5{0};
};

static void TestRelaxedMemoryOrdering() {
  while (1) {
    {
      RelaxedMemoryOrdering rmo;
      rmo.Test();
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
  }//while loop
}


int main()
{
    TestRelaxedMemoryOrdering();
}
```

Comment: an example of possible failure without fences: https://bartoszmilewski.com/2008/11/05/who-ordered-memory-fences-on-an-x86/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Intel x86 architecture processors, the `MOV` instruction automatically has acquire-release semantics, so it might not be possible to observe the reordering you would expect from relaxed semantics. However, you should not rely on this, because the compiler is still allowed to reorder instructions for optimization purposes.

See https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html

Comment: Sorry but could you please point me the text in the link where it says so. I don't see where it says MOV implicitly results into acquire-release semantics.

Comment: @Monku "Load Acquire: MOV (from memory)" "Store Release: MOV (into memory)"

Comment: Yea but my load and stores above are `explicitly` using relaxed ordering.

Comment: @Monku That's not the point. There is no x86 instruction that is less strict than `MOV`. So you are getting acquire-release semantics at minimum whether you ask for it or not. That's built into the x86 architecture.